# Slow query - selecting rows where a foreign property does not exist

Tags: sql

I have a Person table, and a Place table with fields Person, Type, and PhoneNumber.  I want to find all entries in the Person table who don't have a home phone number.  The problem is, they either might not have a home in the table, or they might have a home but with no home phone number.  (One Person can have an arbitrary number of associated Places, so I can't just check for *no* associated places.)

My current query looks like

```
SELECT ID from Person LEFT JOIN Place on Person.ID = Place.Person WHERE 
(Place.Type = 'home' AND Place.Phone IS NULL)
OR (NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT * FROM Place where Person.ID = Place.Person and Place.Type= 'home'))
```

The problem is that the subquery is really slow since it's not doing a join.  How can I improve performance, either by using a join within the subquery or by some other trick?

Comment: What is the schema for your tables?  Are you using SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify it to:

```
select id from person left join place on id = person
and type = 'home'
where phone is null
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT ID 
from   Person 
       LEFT JOIN Place 
         on Person.ID = Place.Person 
         and Place.Type = 'home'
WHERE  Place.Phone IS NULL
       Or Place.Type Is NULL
```

Comment: There's a one-to-many relationship from Person to Place, though.  I'll add that into the question.

Comment: the filter on type is null is unnecessary

Comment: @DanBracuk - after reading your response, I see that you're right.  However, it still think it's worth trying based on indexes that may or may not exist on the table.